# vbulletin replacing equal sign in html code

Tags: html, vbulletin

I have a problem with vbulletin forum

check this page

[VB](https://www.fxprg.com/vb/showthread.php?t=32986)

the problem with threads its replacing equal sign = in html code with =

for example

color="#006400"

instead of

color="#006400"

[image: Html Code]

who can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in this page

vb/includes/class_bbcode.php

line 1552

I changed this code

```
$replace = array('&#039;', '&#0061;');
```

with this one

```
$replace = array('&#039;', '=');
```

so the problem was in bbcode plugin